# Solve multiple equations

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to use [`solve()`](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_102.html#solve) to get two variables for a power function.

It looks to me, according to the documentation, that I can do the following:

```
solve ([b*8^a=6,b*18^a=2], [a,b]);
```

I use the following notation for a power function:

```
f(x) = b * x^a
```

Let's say that I have two points (8, 6) and (18, 2) and the graph goes through both points.

In wxMaxima I tried to do:

```
%i1 solve ([b*8^a=6,b*18^a=2], [a,b]);
%o1 []
```

Now, I know that I can use define formulas to find `a` and `b`, but that is rather long compared to the above. Am I missing some setting for `solve()`?

Below is my current way to get to get the calculation rule for a power function:

```
findA: a=(log(y_2/y_1)/log(x_2/x_1));

findB: b = y_1/x_1^a;

[x_1=8,y_1=6,x_2=18,y_2=2];

subst (%, findA), numer;
a=-1.354755645675727

subst ([x_1=8,y_1=6,x_2=18,y_2=2,a=-1.354755645675727], findB), numer;
b=100.37313960722
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the `log` function to transform the equations into something `solve` can handle.

```
(%i2) e: [b*8^a=6, b*18^a=2];
                        a          a
(%o2)                 [8  b = 6, 18  b = 2]
(%i3) log(e);
                  a                    a
(%o3)       [log(8  b) = log(6), log(18  b) = log(2)]
```

I need to encourage Maxima to simplify `log` further.

```
(%i4) log(e), logexpand = true;
                  a                    a
(%o4)       [log(8  b) = log(6), log(18  b) = log(2)]
```

Hmm, need to try still harder.

```
(%i5) log(e), logexpand = super;
(%o5) [log(b) + log(8) a = log(6), log(b) + log(18) a = log(2)]
```

Okay, that looks solvable. I'll try `solve` again.

```
(%i6) solve (%o5, [a, b]);
(%o6)                          []
```

Oh, I see it's a function of `log(b)`. I can tell `solve` to consider `log(b)` as a variable to solve for.

```
(%i7) solve (%o5, [a, log(b)]);
            log(6) - log(2)
(%o7) [[a = ----------------, log(b) = 
            log(8) - log(18)
                                 log(2) log(8) - log(6) log(18)
                                 ------------------------------]]
                                        log(8) - log(18)
```

Great, I got a solution, now I'll look at the numerical value.

```
(%i8) float (%);
(%o8) [[a = - 1.354755645675727, log(b) = 4.608894637671451]]
```

Comment: The last step is then to do `solve (log(b)=4.608894637671451, b);` and the `float` of the result. Thanks!